# process.StandardOutput retrieving only partial data

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to run an exe using process in the c# console application and getting the output written line by line to a TXT file. This is supposed to recursively run across all the sub folder files.

This perfectly works when I run with the folders having less files. But when this is run at the top level folders having huge list of files or at the drive level (like D:\ or E:\ ) this doesn't provide the whole output and it stops in between saying its complete. This happens the same with console output as well.

Tried to enable Standarderror and output that as well, but was not able to get any errors though. Please suggest why this would complete with partial data and doesn't run through the whole list?

```
Process sigCheckProcess = new Process();
sigCheckProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sigcheckdir + "\\sigcheck64.exe";
sigCheckProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a -h -i -l -s " + dir;
sigCheckProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
sigCheckProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
sigCheckProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
sigCheckProcess.Start();

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText(@"D:\Sigcheckoutput.txt"))
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = sigCheckProcess.StandardOutput)
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var content = sigCheckProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            streamWriter.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
}
sigCheckProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Can someone please help to understand if this is a buffer issue or deadlock issue? It could be of great help if someone can help to fix my problem on how I can use the logic. I am using the same logic of above save in csv instead with some filter options as I don't need the complete output.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo sigCheckProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
sigCheckProcess.FileName = "\\sigcheck64.exe";
sigCheckProcess.Arguments = "-a -h -i -l -s " ;
sigCheckProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
sigCheckProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
sigCheckProcess.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(sigCheckProcess))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    string line;
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("output.txt")) // output txt file.
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\", "test.txt")))  // replaces sigCheckProcess.StandardOutput
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
Process.Start(sigCheckProcess).WaitForExit();

using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("output.txt")) // output txt file.
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\", "test.txt")))  // replaces sigCheckProcess.StandardOutput
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```